# Create PDF in browser: Custom Font

Tags: javascript, pdf, fonts, browser

I know two libraries to create PDF files using Javascript in the browser ([[1]](https://code.google.com/p/jspdf/), [[2]](https://github.com/Marak/pdf.js)) but none of them allows to embed a custom font into the document.
[[2]](https://github.com/Marak/pdf.js) allows to set a custom font, but only for the standard PDF fonts (Courier, Times-Roman) and none of them is actively developed anymore.

Does anyone know a library to create PDF files in the browser that is still actively developed and supports the embedding of custom fonts?

Cheers,

Manuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, looks like current implementations do not support it.
So I'm porting libharu to javascript using emscripten:

Project:
https://github.com/manuels/hpdf.js

Demos:
http://manuels.github.com/hpdf.js/

Comment: can I use for ARabic and Urdu(RTL) text?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking, there's also this: https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit

It looks more actively developed than hpdf, BUT I couldn't get it working just using browserify with the node module brfs as the docs mention (firstly brfs only works with static paths, but it also didn't seem to output the raw data from the font properly), I had to do this to get it to work:

- if your font has no cmap: open, then export the font as ttf (with glyph map in the export options) with fontforge
- get the base64 of the ttf file in string format (I used python to read the contents of the ttf file, encode with base64, remove line breaks, then save out to another file)
- paste the string as a variable in your script
- create a buffer object, and pass that as the font with pdfkit, ie

  ```
  fontCenturyGothicBase64 = "your base64 encoded string here";
  fontCenturyGothic = new Buffer(fontCenturyGothicBase64, 'base64');

  doc.font(fontCenturyGothic);
  ```
- use browserify on the javascript file (Buffer is a node object rather than pure js)

Maybe it's possible without using the Buffer object (and thus browserify), I haven't tried.